# React typescript import syntax issues with vscode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, meteor-react, typescript-typings

I just started testing with react typescript + Meteor and I cannot figure out how to setup VSCode properly.

TSX and TS file react autocomplete and syntax highlighting works fine, but every module import trickers vscode critical errors.

```
[ts] Cannot find module 'react'
[ts] Cannot find module 'react-dom'
```

My import statement below.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
```

Components load fine so imports actually are working, but I get syntax highlighting issues for every import and I want to fix this.

I do not have any tsconfig.json files or typings folder.

I am using https://github.com/barbatus/typescript to automatically transpile typescript files for meteor build. Background this has both typings files tsconfig.json.

Comment: Do you have react.d.ts and react-dom.d.ts in your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to get typings for `react` and `react-dom`.

## QUICK:

`npm install --save-dev @types/react @types/react-dom`.

Similar for react-dom.

Comment: I accepted the answer as it must be right one. For some reason importing react will still give issues and I actually already had react typings globally installed, but once I installed react-dom typings that error went away. Next I try to reinstall my react typings and update typings package itself.

Answer (score 2):

instead of typings use npm directly.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have tsconfig file.